# What is the difference in interpretation between adding ellipse.type = "confidence" in PCA biplots?

Tags: confidence-interval, pca, canonical-correlation, ellipse

I am trying to identify if three groups of species (like here) overlap or seperate out. I tried a popular method to identify ellipses:

```
data(iris)
res.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5],  scale = TRUE)

fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca, label = "var", habillage=iris$Species,
                addEllipses=TRUE, ellipse.level=0.95,
                ggtheme = theme_minimal())


fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca, label = "var", habillage=iris$Species,
                addEllipses=TRUE, ellipse.level=0.95,ellipse.type = "confidence",
                ggtheme = theme_minimal())
```

The first produced:

[image]

I *think* this draws ellipses of some kind around the centroid. I would interpret this as blue and green species share common traits but red uses completely different traits

This is the second one:

[image]

I *think* this draws 95% confidence ellipses of some kind around the centroid. I would interpret this as all three blue, green and red have completely different traits.

I am trying to understand how to interpert each of these graphs? More importantly, what kind of statistics should I be reporting to talk about extent of overlap? Alternately, I tried to look up ellipses from the `vegan package` sensu Oksanen. But I only found NMDS plots not regular PCA

Comment: What does the help manual for this software say about these ellipses?  The first set looks like a high-percentile contour of a Normal approximation to each group while the second looks like a confidence region for the mean of each group, but what *exactly* they show is a matter you need to consult the documentation for.

Comment: @whuber well I'm not sure because the documentation is not very extensive. For ellipse.level is says "the size of the concentration ellipse in normal probability" I always presumend that this was 95% confidence itnterval till I discovered `ellipse.type = "confidence"` I can't see a documentation for this particular phrase but it does something different to my graphs. I am not sure how to interpret each of these.